# get all the classes of an element with specific class using javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to get the previous class of an elements using JavaScript.

```
<li class="dynamic_class second_dynamic_class xx "></li>
<li class="dynamic_class second_dynamic_class"></li>
```

I want to put into a var and compare the `dymanic_class` of the `<li>` with the `class="xx"`.

ONLY pure JavaScript allowed !

Further Details:

```
<li class='day_1 24.02.2013' data-name='day_1 24.02.2013' >
more code
</li>
<li class='day_2 25.02.2013 today' data-name='day_2 25.02.2013' >
more code
</li>
<li class='day_3 26.02.2013' data-name='day_3 26.02.2013' >
more code
</li>
<li class='day_4 27.02.2013' data-name='day_4 27.02.2013' ></li>
```

First I need to select the < li> with the class today than read the "previous" < li> class of the same element, i need to obtain the class="day_1" into a var.

Comment: Could you please further explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is a "previous class"? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I have to select the specific < li > element with the class="xx" and read this element other classes, finaly compare one of these classes with anothe element class.

Comment: What if more than one <li> element has the class "xx"?

Comment: Impossible, I give the xx class using another javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've made it, the code looks like this:

I have multiple elements with different classes:

`<li class='day_1 24.02.2013' data-name='day_1 24.02.2013' >more code</ li>`
`<li class='day_2 25.02.2013 ' data-name='day_2 25.02.2013' >more code</ li>`
`<li class='day_3 26.02.2013 today' data-name='day_3 26.02.2013' >more code</li>`
`<li class='day_4 27.02.2013' data-name='day_4 27.02.2013' >more code</ li>`

I wanted to put into a variable (using just javascript code) the first class of the `<li>` element which also has the today class so I used the following code:

`var now=' ';`
`var demo= document.getElementsByTagName("li");`
`for (var i = 0; i < demo.length; i++ ) {`

```
if (demo[i].className.indexOf('today')!=-1) {
    if (demo[i].className.indexOf('day_1')!=-1){
        now = 'sunday';
    }else if(demo[i].className.indexOf('day_2')!=-1) {
        now = 'monday';
    }else if(demo[i].className.indexOf('day_3')!=-1) {
        now = 'tuesday';
    }else {
        now = 'wednesday';
    }   
} /* first if - ends here */
```

`} /* for - ends here */`

```
 alert(now);
```

Now you can select the first or second class of the `<li>` with the class "today".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var results = document.getElementById('targetId').className.split(' ');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no targetId to identify the element. Starting from your eg. I tryed: var element = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
if (element.className == "today") { //need some code } but I'm lost, need some extra code!

Comment: var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); getElementsByTagName returns array of elements, so instead of elements.className you should write elements[0].className (or iterate through for and get all element's classNames)